# Not Able To Get Document Directory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code to get to the documents directory.  It works fine in the first ViewController but when I push a new ViewController the exact same code returns nothing.  The documentPath is nil. Here is the code:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databaseFile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SCSDirectory"];
```

I have read through the other posts but none of them seem to address this issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated - I am losing my mind.

Thanks.

Comment: The code in question seems fine. You should share some more information about the context surrounding the call: in which method ? Do you store the results ? return it ? It could just be that you are weakly referencing it and so the reference would be set to nil since nobody seems to strongly hold on to it

Comment: I'm not sure why that isn't working in the second view controller since it looks correct to me. Since it's just returning a string it's not necessary to run that code more than once. Have you tried just passing `documentsPath` into the second view controller so you can use it there?